# Render angular directives in Selectize.js items

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-directive, selectize.js

I am using [angular-selectize](https://github.com/machineboy2045/angular-selectize) to use [Selectize.js](https://selectize.github.io/selectize.js/) in my angular project.

To use custom items in Selectize.js selector, I am using Selectize.js' [render](https://github.com/brianreavis/selectize.js/blob/master/docs/usage.md#rendering) option:

```
render: {
  item: function(item, escape) {
    var avatar = '<div>' +
        '<span avatars="\'' + escape(item._id) +'\'" class="avatars">' +
        '</span>' +
        escape(item.nick) +
      '</div>';
    var compiledAvatar =  $compile(avatar)($rootScope);
    $timeout();
    return compiledAvatar.html();
  },
```

where avatars is a custom directive with asychronous behaviour

The problem is that the `render.item` function expects an HTML string as an output *but*:

- There is no way of returning a rendered or "`$compile`ed" HTML string in a synchronous way as expected by `render.item` method.
- I do not know how to render that item's elements afterwards when they have already been added to the DOM.

Note that although $compile is called, returned string would not be the expected compiled result but the string before compilation due to the asynchronous nature of $compile.

Comment: Added as an issue in angular-selectize's github: https://github.com/machineboy2045/angular-selectize/issues/142

Comment: Might not be the prefered way of doing things, but could you use promises to get the synchronous behavior you want?

Comment: @Pytth, I dont know how a promise could help here, please note that `render.item` function needs to return a html `string`, not a promise. Please share any ideas on how to use promises for this issue. Thanks!

Comment: Do you really need to use $compile() and $timeout()? Pretty sure it is not possible inside render.item, because selectize expects it to be sync function. Have you tried simply returning avatar as html string?

Comment: You are right @andree, $compile and $timeout are not needed. I have included them in the example so the problem can be seen. I have updated the question to better reflect this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer is based in the helpful answer by @gregori with the following differences:

1. Take into account Selectize.js' Render Cache. The standard behaviour of Selectize.js is that the items are cached as returned by the render function, and not with the modifications we have done to them. After adding and deleting some elements, the cached and not the modified version would be displayed if we do not update the render cache acordingly.
2. Using random id's to identify the elements to select to be manipulated from DOM.
3. Using watchers to know when the compilation has been done

First, we define a method to modify the selectize.js render cache:

```
scope.selectorCacheUpdate = function(key, value, type){

  var cached = selectize.renderCache[type][key];

  // update cached element
  var newValue = angular.element(cached).html(value);

  selectize.renderCache[type][key] = newValue[0].outerHTML;

  return newValue.html();
};
```

Then, the render function is defined as follows:

```
function renderAvatar(item, escape, type){

  // Random id used to identify the element
  var randomId = Math.floor(Math.random() * 0x10000000).toString(16);

  var avatar = 
    '<div id="' + randomId + '">' +
      '<span customAvatarTemplate ...></span>' +
      ...
    '</div>';

  var compiled = $compile(avatar)($rootScope);

  // watcher to see when the element has been compiled
  var destroyWatch = $rootScope.$watch(
    function (){
      return compiled[0].outerHTML;
    },
    function (newValue, oldValue){
      if(newValue !== oldValue){

        var elem = angular.element(document.getElementById(randomId));

        var rendered = elem.scope().selectorCacheUpdate(item._id, compiled.html(), type);

        // Update DOM element
        elem.html(rendered);

        destroyWatch();
      }
    }
  );
});

return avatar;
```

}

*Note:* The key for the render cache is the `valueField` of the selectize items, in this case, `_id`

Finally, we add this function as a selectize render function in the selectize configuration object:

```
config = {
  ...
  render: {
    item: function(i,e){
      return renderAvatar(i, e, 'item');
    },
    option: function(i,e){
      return renderAvatar(i, e, 'option');
    }
  },
  ...
}
```

For more details, see how this solution has been added to the application that motivated this question: https://github.com/P2Pvalue/teem/commit/968a437e58c5f1e70e80cc6aa77f5aefd76ba8e3.

Answer (score 1):

One idea is to use DOM manipulation which is not the most recommended Angular way, but I got it [working on this plunker.](https://plnkr.co/edit/dPNudltZfOk3oKmZVBnW) and a [second one with custom directive and randomized data to simulate your compiled avatar.](https://plnkr.co/edit/lIhHTX411NrHqRFaSTyd)

To simulate your asynchronous call, I use ngResource. My render function returns a string `"<div class='compiledavatar'>Temporary Avatar</div>"` with a special class markup `compiledavatar`. For a second or two, you will see Temporary Avatar as you select an element. When the ngResource calls finishes I look for the element with class `compiledavatar` and then replace the html with what I downloaded. Here is the full code:

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', ['selectize', 'ngResource']);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $resource, $document) {
  var vm = this;
  vm.name = 'World';
  vm.$resource = $resource;
  vm.myModel = 1;
  vm.$document = $document;

  vm.myOptions = [{
    id: 1,
    title: 'Spectrometer'
  }, {
    id: 2,
    title: 'Star Chart'
  }, {
    id: 3,
    title: 'Laser Pointer'
  }];

  vm.myConfig = {
    create: true,
    valueField: 'id',
    labelField: 'title',
    delimiter: '|',
    placeholder: 'Pick something',
    onInitialize: function(selectize) {
      // receives the selectize object as an argument
    },
    render: {
      item: function(item, escape) {
        var label = item.title;
        var caption = item.id;
        var Stub = vm.$resource('mydata', {});
        // This simulates your asynchronous call

        Stub.get().$promise.then(function(s) {
          var result = document.getElementsByClassName("compiledavatar")
          angular.element(result).html(s.compiledAvatar);

          // Once the work is done, remove the class so next time this element wont be changed
          // Remove class
          var elems = document.querySelectorAll(".compiledavatar");
          [].forEach.call(elems, function(el) {
              el.className = el.className.replace(/compiledavatar/, "");
          });

        });

        return "<div class='compiledavatar'>Temporary Avatar</div>"
      }
    },
    // maxItems: 1
  };
});
```

To simulate the JSON API I just created a file in plunker `mydata`:

```
{
    "compiledAvatar": "<div><span style='display: block; color: black; font-size: 14px;'>an avatar</span></div>"
  }
```

Of course your compiled function should return you something different every calls. Me it gives me the same to demonstrate the principle.

In addition, if your dynamic code is an Agular directive, here is a [second plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/lIhHTX411NrHqRFaSTyd) with a custom directive and randomized data so you can better see the solution:

The data include a custom directive `my-customer`:

```
[{
    "compiledAvatar": "<div><span style='display: block; color: black; font-size: 14px;'>an avatar  #1  <my-customer></my-customer></span></div>"
  },
  {
    "compiledAvatar": "<div><span style='display: block; color: black; font-size: 14px;'>an avatar  #2  <my-customer></my-customer></span></div>"
  },
(...)
```

The directive is defined as:

```
app.directive('myCustomer', function() {
  return {
    template: '<div>and a custom directive</div>'
  };
});
```

And the main difference in the app is that you have to add $compile when replacing the HTML and the text should show `An avatar #(number) and a custom directive`. I get an array of json value and use a simple random to pick a value. Once the HTML is replaced I remove the class, so next time only the last added element will be changed.

```
 Stub.query().$promise.then(function(s) {
      var index = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
      var result = document.getElementsByClassName("compiledavatar")
      angular.element(result).html($compile(s[index].compiledAvatar)($scope));

      // Remove class
      var elems = document.querySelectorAll(".compiledavatar");
      [].forEach.call(elems, function(el) {
        el.className = el.className.replace(/compiledavatar/, "");
      });
});
```

Also, I looked at selectize library and you cant return a promise... as it does a html.replace on the value returned by render. This is why I went to the route of a temporary string with a class to retrieve later and update. 
Let me know if that helps.

Comment: Unfortunatelly this solution has some issues and is not working completelly due to Selectize.js cache of rendered elements. Please, see my following answer for a solution of this issue: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38640167/4928558

Comment: @atfornes Good catch. I did not experience the cache issue in my testing, but thank you for improving the solution and sharing with us.